# Automatic registration of derived classes in a factory pattern

Tags: c++, c++11, factory

For an application I'm writing, an important part is that the user can select any of available options for different processes. All these options are derived from the same base class. I do add new options once in a while though, and I wanted to make this process as easy as possible. So, after looking around the web and SO, here is what I have:

Base class:

```
class Base {
    double some_member;
    virtual double some_method() = 0;
};
```

Derived class:

```
class Derived : Base {
//...
};
```

A factory to hold a table of available types and create a derived class based on an assigned name:

```
template <typename B>
class Factory{
public:
    template <typename D>
    void registerType(std::string name)
    {
        static_assert(std::is_base_of<B, D>::value, "class doesn't derive from the base");
        table_[name] = &createFunc<D>;
    }
    B* create(std::string name)
    {
        const auto it = table_.find(name);
        if(it != table_.end())
            return it->second();
        FILE_LOG(logERROR) << "unidentified option, acceptable options are:";
        for(auto const &m : list())
            FILE_LOG(logERROR) << '\t' << m;
        return nullptr;
    }

    std::vector<std::string> list()
    {
        std::vector<std::string> lst;
        for(auto const &iter : table_)
            lst.push_back(iter.first);
        return lst;
    }
private:
    template<typename D>
    static B* createFunc()
    {
        return new D();
    }
    typedef B* (*PCreateFunc)();
    std::map<std::string, PCreateFunc> table_;
};
```

A class that contains all the options for a certain process:

```
class OptsContainer {
private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> opts_;
public:
    //some other stuff
    void addOption(const std::string &); //adds a new option with given name
    static Factory<Base> factory;
};

Factory<Base> OptsContainer::factory;

void OptsContainer::addOption(const std::string &name)
{
    opts_.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Base>(factory.create(name)));
}
```

At this point, whenever I add a new derived class, I just need to register the class in the factory table:

```
///All older includes
#include "derived42.h"

void initOptions()
{
    //all other registrations
    OptsContainer::factory.registerType<Derived42>("Derived42");
}
```

And I call `initOptions` at the very beginning of my program. This is working great, but I feel that it should be possible to make it even better. What I want is to have to only add `#include "derived42"` and the type to register itself, therefore no need for the `initOptions` function and calling it at the very beginning.

Do I have to use Boost/Loki/... (as mentioned in another post)? Is this even possible in vanilla c++? or should I just live with what I have at the moment? Just FYI, I'm using Visual Studio Express 2015 to write my program, but I can move the code to Linux as well (gcc). In other words, prefer not using c++11/c++14 patterns that are not implemented in VS2015, but if I need to, I can easily move everything to gcc.

Comment: Don't forget the virtual destructor for the base class. :) Also, "Visual Studio Express 2015"? Do you mean Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition"?

Comment: @Casey Thanks for reminding me, I should do that :-) about your second question, no, I mean express version. If I remember correctly, I had some problems with the way the license is worded in community edition, so I decided to be safe and use express :-)

Comment: Pretty certain it's not possible. maps can only be populated in run-time, so there should be a call which is done in run-time.

Comment: Your code provides already a minimum effort to register a type (The inclusion of the class declaration and the registration of that class - you need both anyways). However, if your factory is inside a library and you want to register a class from outside, it will not be possible. If that is not required, kudos!

Comment: What you're trying to do achieve here is the *pluggable factory pattern*. The usual way of implementing auto-registration is by using static initialisers, and the easiest way of generating these is with a class template with a static member, whose construction performs the registration with the pluggable factory.  You can do this in C++03, although it was traditionally a bit of a crap-shoot as to whether your tool-chain actually worked.

Comment: @marko thanks, I'll take a look into these pluggable factory patterns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks too complicated to me. Maybe there is a reason that I miss.

You cannot avoid the registration.  What you are looking for is registration at compile time, which I think it is not possible. Since you are looking for registration at compile time, it means that you do not need to expose the registration method in interface. So, your client interface should be made of the base class and a creation method:

```
// { client interface header
class B
{
public:
  virtual ~B() = 0 {}
  //...
};

B* Create( const char* s );
// } client interface header
```

A simple creation function:

```
// { client interface implementation

template< typename T >
B* New()
{
  return new T;
}

typedef B* (*PFNew)();

B* Create( const char* s )
{
  typedef std::map< string, PFNew > Map;

  static Map m;
  if ( ! m.size() )
  {
    m[ D1::Signature() ] = New< D1 >;
    m[ D2::Signature() ] = New< D2 >;
    //...
  }

  Map::const_iterator ci = m.find( s );
  if ( ci == m.end() )
    throw -1;
  return ci->second();
}

// } client interface implementation
```

Comment: Thanks, so whenever I add a new derived class, I just add another line in the `Create` method. Your method IS easier. I can use the factory class for different base classes, but adding a secondary template your method can do that too :-) Thanks again.